# How to redirect to another page when page is deleted

Tags: php, redirect, header

In my website i'm trying to redirect to another page when something is deleted.

In my case I created events and each event got his own page (fe: `event.php?event_id=20`). When I am on the eventpage I can delete the event. But if i redirect to another page with the action tag it isn't deleting the event. When I stay on the page it delete the event but it stays on the eventpage.

I tried to use header(`"location:..."`) to redirect after the query is done but it isn't doing anything. What I'm I doing wrong?

```
include_once("classes/Event.class.php");
$event = new Event();

if (isset($_POST["btnDeleteEvent"])){
    try{
        $event_id = $_GET['event_id'];
        $event->DeleteEvent($event_id);
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        $feedback = $e->getMessage();
    }   

}


<form class='event_center' class='form-horizontal' action='<?php echo "event.php" . "?event_id=" .$event_id; ?>' method='post'> <img src="images/trash_white.png"/>
            <button type='submit' name='btnDeleteEvent'  >Delete</button></form>
```

(here i am executing the query on the page I am but it has to go to `events.php`)

function:

```
public function DeleteEvent($event_id){
        $db = new Db();

        $select = "DELETE from tblevents WHERE event_id = " . $event_id . "";  
        $result = $db->conn->query($select);
        return $result;
        header("Location: events.php");
    }
```

Comment: The code after the `return $result` will never be executed. Therefore the user is not sent to `events.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the

```
header("Location: events.php");
```

before

```
    return $result;
```

the function terminates at line

```
    return $result;
```

so it can't reach to the `header` statement

Try this :

```
public function DeleteEvent($event_id){
    $db = new Db();

    $select = "DELETE from tblevents WHERE event_id = " . $event_id . "";  
    $result = $db->conn->query($select);
    header("Location: events.php");
}
```